# communication with android over the Internet

Tags: ros, rosjava, android, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to make an app on Android that will receive:
-stream video from cameras
-map
-some other data like velocity, state of program etc.

The app should also send some requests.

Could You help me how can i achieve this?
Should I use ROSjava or it won't give me all the needed features?
Maybe use websockets?[rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) ?Or sth else (protocol/technology), especially for video streaming? If u could show me some examples or share some thoughts, it would be nice.
Sadly i am new to java/android and network programming.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204712/communication-with-android-over-the-internet/) by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2015-03-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good starting point would be the camera_tutprial_app from rosjava. It streams data from the camera (using the old API) to a ros node.

---

Originally posted by [jmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/22041/jmr/) with karma: 16 on 2015-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0